# cannot open entry for reading while its open for writing csv file while executing the rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

> Rake aborted!
>
> cannot open entry for reading while its open for writing - ddh8484000adshdjas.csv

I am getting above error, when I am running my task. I try closing the csv file with `close()`, but nothing working for me. Any help on this.

Below is my code

```
          CSV.open("#{rootDir}/#{filename}.csv", "w") do |csv|
            data.each do | array |
              csv << array
            end
            csv.close()
          end
          zip_file_path = "filename.zip"
          Zip::ZipFile.open(zip_file_path, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) { |zipfile|
            Dir.glob("#{rootDir}/*.csv").each do |file|
                zipfile.get_output_stream(file.split("/")[8]);
                file.close()
            end
          }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you don't need the `csv.close()`, the file will be closed at the end of the block.

Comment: Also, why do you call `get_output_stream`? Do you need to add the CSV files to the ZIP file or do you need to add an entry for each file containing something else?

Comment: @cmoran92 -  thanks for the reply, yes I want to add csv file to zip file